# IE8 places @ in closing divs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

We have a system which is built using Kentico, on the home page we have blocks each block contains content we are currently using ISOTOPE.js to display these on the page as shown here (from firefox) :

[image]

As you can see its spaced evenly.

We have recently been informed this site needs to work within IE8 so using browser stack I inspect each page, the blocks shown above do no render correctly within IE8 instead they look like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is no space between each block instead it is one hole block.  Now using browser stack I have managed to inspect the element in IE8 and below is what HTML I see

[image]

As you can see each closing div has a '@' sign in it, my question is how is this happening? When viewed in FF, chrome earlier version of IE it displays as expected?